# How to Migrate Stackechange account to a new one?

Tags: discussion, support, user-accounts, merge-accounts

I currently have a stackexchange account setup with my yahoo id but I prefer signing in with my Google account on stackexchange sites and I've got more accounts setup with my Google account than my Yahoo ID.

I'd like to migrate my stack exchange accounts with my yahoo id to my Google account without losing the state of the account, i.e reps, badges and all that.

I read an answer on a question that was similar to mine about adding a new "open id"  next to the "edit" link, but I never saw such button on my account's profile page.

Comment: "my logins" on the most right from "edit" -- isn't it what you look for?

Comment: No, I have that and it only shows accounts i'm logged in to.

Comment: And if you try to add the other openID to the current account? Sorry, I've never been in that situation, so I'm only guessing

Comment: What happens if you click "add login" at the bottom of the "my logins" page?

Comment: I only get a popup to logout of my current stackexchange site or log in with a different account .

Comment: I do see that, but it doesn't help with the issue i have with moving my old account content to a new one.

Comment: Ok, if you click that then you can add another OpenID to your existing account, like the one you used for the other account.  I suspect that a solution to your problem starts with that, but it sounded like you were saying that you didn't have that "add login" link, which was puzzling.

Comment: Oh. Now I understand. Never thought that feature was there for such purpose. Thank you so much.  Can I then delete the old open id?

Comment: See [How do I add or remove login credentials from my account?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/edit-credentials) in the Help Center.